# I am trying to convert UTC datetime to a specific timezone in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an XML file which has a datetime value. I loop through the elements and get the attribute value `timeutc`.

I managed to convert it to local time zone, but what I am trying to do is convert it to any time zone, PST, CST, EST.

```
$Appointments = '<appointments><appointment timeutc="2013-10-10T06:00:00" /><appointment timeutc="2013-10-10T06:00:00" /><appointment timeutc="2013-10-10T15:00:00" /></appointments>'
index = 0

doc = REXML::Document.new("#{$Appointments}")

doc.elements.each("appointments/appointment") do |element|
  index += 1
  value = element.attribute("timeutc").value

  to_datetime = DateTime.parse(value).to_s
  to_UTC = Time.iso8601(to_datetime).to_s

  local_time = Time.iso8601(to_datetime).localtime

  puts local_time # => 2013-10-09 23:00:00 -0700 

  puts   local_time.strftime("%A") # => Wednesday
  puts   local_time.strftime("%B") # => October
  puts   local_time.strftime("%-d") # => 9
  puts   local_time.strftime("%l") # => 11
  puts   local_time.strftime("%M") # => 00
  puts   local_time.strftime("%p") # => PM

end
```

Comment: What is the source format of the date?  ISO or other?

Comment: Don't use `$Appointments`. A global isn't necessary for this and a local `appointments` is more acceptable. `"#{$Appointments}"` is also not needed because it's already a string. Also, you initialize and increment `index` but do nothing useful with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [in_time_zone](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Zones/in_time_zone) method:

For CST:

```
local_time.in_time_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)')
```

For PST:

```
local_time.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

For EST:

```
local_time.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

Comment: It gives me an error. I am using RubyMine. This might work for ruby on rails.
Test.rb:38:in `block in <main>': undefined method `in_time_zone' for 2013-10-09
23:00:00 -0700:Time (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb:905:in `block in each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb:67:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb:67:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb:905:in `each'
        from Test.rb:17:in `<main>'

Comment: Are you using rails or is it just ruby?

Comment: Yes. I am using just ruby and not rails.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's support for time zones hasn't been that great (not sure if this has changed with 2.0), hence the various ActiveSupport libs.

Ruby looks to the environment variable `TZ` to determine what zone to operate in:

```
irb [1.9.3]$ ENV["TZ"]  # Ruby will look elsewhere and see that I'm in NYC
=> nil
irb [1.9.3]$ Time.iso8601 "2013-10-10T06:00:00"
=> 2013-10-10 06:00:00 -0400
irb [1.9.3]$ ENV["TZ"]="America/Los_Angeles"
=> "America/Los_Angeles"
irb [1.9.3]$ Time.now.zone
=> "PDT"
irb [1.9.3]$ Time.iso8601 "2013-10-10T06:00:00"
=> 2013-10-10 06:00:00 -0700
```

So... while I'd strongly encourage using the active support methods, you could use something like this:

```
irb [1.9.3]$ def parse_in_zone(date, zone)
1{             old = ENV["TZ"]
1{             ENV["TZ"] = zone
1{             Time.iso8601 date
1{           ensure
1*             ENV["TZ"] = old
1{           end
=> nil
irb [1.9.3]$ parse_in_zone "2013-10-10T06:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles"
=> 2013-10-10 06:00:00 -0700
irb [1.9.3]$ parse_in_zone "2013-10-10T06:00:00", "America/New_York"
=> 2013-10-10 06:00:00 -0400
```

Also note that `DateTime.parse(value)` is not necessary. It considers the string's zone when parsing the date:

```
irb [1.9.3]$ DateTime.parse("2013-10-10T06:00:00").zone
=> "+00:00"
irb [1.9.3]$ DateTime.parse("2013-10-10T06:00+04:00").zone
=> "+04:00"
irb [1.9.3]$ DateTime.parse("2013-10-10T06:00+07:00").zone
=> "+07:00"
```

Note that in your case I don't think the string: `2013-10-10T06:00:00` is a valid iso date/time (extra `:00`) but it looks like ruby doesn't care:

```
irb [1.9.3]$ DateTime.parse("2013-10-10T06:00:0000:000000").to_s
=> "2013-10-10T06:00:00+00:00"
```